# Pivot tables: Summarizing a list of fields that have a value in one field but not the other field

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a set of data and made a pivot table with three columns as follows:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nq06q51hjoi0s01/ww.png

Now what I would like is to know what are the countries that have Accessories sales but no computer sales.. What I've done is I've sorted the computer sales column from smallest to largest then it turned out to be similar to this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7v60vr4dfk7yyg8/qq.png

and then I copied the list of countries starting from the top to the end of the zero sales and moved it into a new sheet.. I have a lot of data that I need to do this withand I'm sure there's gotta be a more efficient/effective way to do it.. Is there something in pivot tables or charts (maybe in the value field settings or something) that can answer and represent this in a neat way for me ? keep in mind that  the country should have sales in accessories but not computers (so turkey for example shouldn't be in the list because it has no sales in computers nor accessories)

Any help or ideas are appreciated.. I would like to do this with pivot tables or charts simply because it summarizes everything in a presentable way.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to answer your question without the file itself. I have downloaded both dropbox file but the content are the same.

But here is my guess:

I would try to move the computer sales column in the filter box of the pivot (top left box). Than in the created filter press the dropbdown filter icon and select the value 0.
The same should be done with acc. sales. THe only difference is in the dropdown check the select multiple options and uncheck the 0.

Not so nice solution is to create a formula in column D, let's say column B is Acc. and column C is computer.

IF(B2<>0;(IF(C2=0;"YES";"NO");"NO")

Than you just have to make a filter on the column D and check the "YES" value.